# How to show divs based on drop down selection when validation fails

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a drop down list in my MVC application which displays certain fields based on the selection.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#ddlReportType").change(function () {
            $("#pnlReport").show();
            if ($(this).val() == 'type1') {
                $("#pnlType1").show();
            }
            if ($(this).val() == 'type2') {
                $("#pnlType2").show();
            }

        });

    });
```

pnlReport is a div with display set to none, but is made visible once a selection is made with ddlReportType.

Here's my dropdownlist:

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Type of Report</label>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(
                x => x.Report.ReportType,
                Model.ReportTypes,
                "", new { @class = "ddl", @id = "ddlReportType", @style = "width:100%" })
            </div>

        </div>
```

And here are my divs:

```
        <div id="pnlReport" style="display:none">
        // A bunch of fields shared across all reports
             <div id="pnlType1" style="display:none">
             // fields specific to Type1 Reports
             </div>
             <div id="pnlType2" style="display:none">
             // fields specific to Type2 Reports
             </div>

        </div>
```

My problem is that if the form validation fails then when the form is resubmitted pnlReport is set to be hidden.  How can I fix this?

I am using MVC 5 with bundled jquery.unobtrusive* and jquery.validate

Comment: In #ddlReportType drop down selection, any default value which won't show #pnlReport?
Could you show your HTML also?

Comment: I've updated my question.  By default, on first entry to the form, pnlReport should be hidden, but after that it should be visible once an item is selected

Comment: what are the possible values in Model.ReportTypes?

Comment: Hi Derek,  4 possible items, basically Type1, Type2, Type3 and Type4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have refactored out the display logic as below. The idea is, trigger DisplayReport in document ready event, such that when the page refreshed after resubmitted, we can display the same view.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function DisplayReport(reportType)
    {
        $("#pnlReport").hide();         
        $("#pnlType1").hide();
        $("#pnlType2").hide();
        // hide all before show
        var showReportPanel = false;

        if (reportType == 'type1') {
            $("#pnlType1").show();
            showReportPanel = true;
        }
        if (reportType == 'type2') {
            $("#pnlType2").show();
            showReportPanel = true;
        }

        if(showReportPanel)
        {
            $("#pnlReport").show();
        }       
    }

    DisplayReport($("#ddlReportType").val());
    $("#ddlReportType").change(function () {        
        DisplayReport($(this).val());
    });
});
```