# hide or show form control based on ddl selection in MVC using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

My problem is similar to the one in [show divs based on drop down selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24226268/how-to-show-divs-based-on-drop-down-selection-when-validation-fails).  I have a dropdown list in a div with four options.  Depending on which is selected I want one of two other controls to show in the next div and in one case it will show an `EditorFor` and I want the value populated.  Here's what I have...

```html
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("OriginType", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.DropDownList("OriginType", ViewData["OriginType"] as SelectList, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group" id="pnlOrigin">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Origin, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div id="pnlOrigin1"class="col-md-4">
        @Html.DropDownList("ddlORDER_10", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Order, "Select an Order Number", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Origin, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
    <div id="pnlOrigin2"class="col-md-4">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Origin, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "tbOrigin" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Origin, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

So what I need is when a user selects from the `OriginType` dropdown (STK, PO, WO, OTHER) it will show or hide the dropdown list or `EditorFor` in the `pnlOrigin` div.  If `PO` or `WO` is selected it will show the ddl.  If `OTHER` or `STK` is selected it will show the `EditorFor`, and in the case of STK it will prepopulate the Editor with `STK`.

I've tried to modify the function in the referenced post but it's not hiding the controls initially and a selection from the `OriginType` dropdown list isn't having any affect?

Here's the jQuery I created.  I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

```javascript
$(document).ready(function () {
    function ShowOptions(originType) {
        if (OriginType == "0"){
            $("#pnlOrigin").hide();
            $("#pnlOrigin1").hide();
            $("#pnlOrigin2").hide();
            // hide all before show
            var showOriginPanel = false;
        }
        if (OriginType == 'STK') {
            $("#pnlOrigin").show();
            $("#tbOrigin").val('STK');
            showOriginPanel = true;
        }
        if (OriginType == 'PO') {
            $("#pnlOrigin1").show();
            showOriginPanel = true;
        }
        if (OriginType == 'WO') {
            $("#pnlOrigin1").show();
            showOriginPanel = true;
        }
        if (OriginType == 'OTHER'){
            $("#pnlOrigin2").show();
            showOriginPanel = true;
        }

        if(showOriginPanel) {
            $("#pnlOrigin").show();
        }       
    }

    ShowOptions($("#OriginType").val());
    $("#OriginType").change(function () {        
        ShowOptions($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you considered accomplishing this using partial views?  It may simplify the process for you dramatically.  Your main view would have the initial drop down and some empty `div`s.  Once a selection is made you send the value to your controller via ajax, and return a partial view to the empty `div` containing the proper drop down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have found the problem with my code although I'm not sure why it affected the function.  I had the htmlAttribues declared for the two hidden controls as "new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } }".  Once I changed them to "htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" }" the function started working properly.

I also had to add some .hides in case the user changed their initial selection prior to posting.